# Commiting changes to github using VS Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I am trying to link VS code with Github and I installed everything neededed.

When I adding some code to the existing file on VS and save it, then trying to push the changes to Github I get an error message that said:

```
there are no changes to commit.
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: what is output from "git status". Did you check that modified file is not in .gitigonore?

Comment: there is no output form git. I will check this out

Comment: how can I find the file in gitigonore?

Comment: you first need to add the changed files to the index/stage

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your changes first, then push it to github. Following explanation uses command line, but you need to follow the same steps using gui.

First, stage the changes:

```sh
git add «file name here»
```

Then, commit changes:

```sh
git commit -m «Here is the commit message»
```

Then, you can push it to github or any other remote repo, if it is added already:

```sh
git push
```